# Nested Resources in Rails 4

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Im attempting to create a Rails app that manages temperatures for a garden.  I have setup my controllers and models appropriately to have resources for Grow - Tray - Plant.
Grow has many trays
Tray has many Plants

Im able to create nested trays in each grow.  But I am not able to create plants in a designated tray.

The [github repo](https://github.com/mgarsteck/grow-manager)

Im getting the following error:
undefined method `tray'
This is for my plant _form

```
<%= form_for([@grow, @grow.tray.plants.build]) do |f| %>
<div class="field">
    <%= f.label :title %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :description %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :description %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :tray_id %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :tray_id %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

The routes look as such:

```
resources :grows do
    resources :trays do
      resources :plants
    end
end
```

The form for building the tray looks like this and it works:

```
<%= form_for([@grow, @grow.trays.build]) do |f| %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :title %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :description %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :description %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :grow_id %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :grow_id %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Is this even the right approach?

Comment: according to your code, you should use `@grow.trays...` instead `@grow.tray`

Comment: Ive tried that as well and i get this for an error
undefined method `plants'
and if i use plant instead of plants, ill get the same error

Answer (score 0):

If Grow `has_many` trays, then `@grow.tray` would be undefined (note the singular).

Perhaps you should assign the relevant Tray in the controller, so it can be referenced in the view appropriately:

```
@tray = @grow.trays.find(...)
```

I'd also recommend avoiding nesting routes more than two levels. Forms like these tend to be more difficult to manage with multiple nesting.

Comment: Ok great, what is a better method for accomplishing this then?

Comment: Also, im still getting the same error.  I added your code to the set_tray action in the plants_controller